# Fixed point of dynamic system

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization

Let $F(\cdot, \cdot)\colon \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bivariate and nonnegative function. Suppose $F(x,y)$ is not convex with repect to $x$ or $y$. Moreover, asusme $F$ is differentiable with respect to the first variable,  $x$, that is, $\nabla_{1} F(x,y)$ exists. Suppose I want to find a point $\theta$ such that 
$$
\nabla _{1} F(x,y)\big |_{x=y = \theta} = 0.
$$
To achieve such a goal, I consider the following two steps:

Step 1. For a fixed $y$, minimize $g(x) = F(x,y)$ and get $\hat x $ such that $\nabla g(\hat x) = 0$.

Step 2. Update $y \leftarrow \hat x$ and repeat step 1 again.

I was wondering under what conditions would such two-step method find a desired $\theta$.

These two steps can be conbined into a two-timescale algorithm as follows, which is a  nonlinear dynamic system
\begin{align}
&x_{t+1} \leftarrow x_t + \alpha_t \cdot \nabla _1 F(x_t, y_t)\\
&y_{t+1} \leftarrow (1- \beta_t) \cdot y_t + \beta_t \cdot x_{t}.
\end{align}
Here we assume $\beta_t / \alpha_t $ converges to zero as $t$ goes to infinity. Will such a algorithm guarantted to find $\theta$?